# Best performances : XML or Java?

Tags: android, performance

Who provides the best performances for Android : XML or Java ?

For example the animation. I can obtain the same result with both Java and XML, using two differents way :

• Java

```
private Animation outToRightAnimation() {
    Animation outToRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    outToRight.setDuration(500);
    outToRight.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    return outToRight;
}
```

• XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Which one is supposed to be faster ? Which one should I use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which one is supposed to be faster ?

They should be close to identical. *Everything* runs through Java. The XML is merely a way of configuring an animation -- that XML is parsed and turned into equivalent Java objects at runtime.

Comment: XML parsing implies that it will be slower than direct java, isn't it?

Comment: i suppose XML parsing will result slower than just writing it in plain Java

Comment: The XML is compile int the apk; it's not as slow as xml parsing. Don't do micro-optiization; it's inflating resources once is not what will make yourr app slow.

Answer (score 1):

Time for XML parsing may matter only if it happens a huge number of times (like in a loop over 100 000 documents), or the XML document is very long (megabytes, for instance). I our case XML document is tiny, it is parsed only once, so it is up to you which approach to use. After the document is parsed, it has no effect on the further performance.

It may be other criteria like how it is easier to write and maintain, but the performance is probably not an issue.